# Navigation properties for non-simple JOINs

Tags: entity-framework

Evening you lovely SO users, I've got a question for you all.

I've recently begun working on an existing project that has a rather heavy database and I'm tasked with making things a little easier on our .NET developers. The general consensus has been that we'd like to use the Entity Framework (or similar), but I'm having problems working out how to map some of the more interesting JOIN clauses we use. I believe I need navigation properties to tie entities together, but I'm not sure how to go about crafting my own. All I've got at the moment are the ones that are generated when I created the model from the database.

I'll give you an example. We've got a table that holds a lot of textual data which may be linked to a customer, supplier, staff member or end user. The data is linked back to these by using the OwnerID field along with the OwnerType field (which holds a single character denoting the type). It may not be ideal, but I'm unable to change the design of the database and I'm wondering if I can get the ORM to handle the nasty work of linking everything together so that our devs can just load the customer record they want and then find the linked text data.

Is this possible? If so, could anyone point me in the direction of some resources to help me sort this out? I've had a good old search, but I don't really know how to word my query.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like the OwnerId is not a foreign key which means you cannot use the navigationproperties correctly.

I havent seen any hacks for this and as you point out yourself it is not a nice solution. The only way to fix this is to redesign your DB or use methods that encapsules this.

Comment: No it isn't a foreign key sadly. Damn, I was afraid that was going to be the case. I guess ORM's aren't for us then. I'm not able to redesign the DB as other applications are reliant on its structure.